# Magento2 Checkout and Admin net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: magento2, error

On this server sometime the Magento 2 admin or checkout will freeze.  I'm working in Chrome and the console will show net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING.

Dedicated server:
CentOS release 6.8
PHP 7.0.7 w/ FPM
nginx/1.11.1
5.6.30-76.3 Percona Server

Similar setup to my local dev VirtualBox which is slow but never has this problem.  Same code different server so I'm assuming there is an issue with the software stack or configuration but have been unable locate.

Guess I'm hoping this issue is familiar to someone.

Comment: Maybe this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29894154/1038727

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Raphael.  I'd seen that post previously but failed to find the answer that help.  Based on the suggestion I revisited:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/29894154/1038727

I found an answer helped me to apparently solve my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36429848/745892

The server in question previously has a different solution stack configured.  During my upgrade for Magento 2 I setup a new magento user for fpm and nginx.  During that process it appears I failed to remove/set permission on the /var/cache/nginx/* directories.  The error log shows sometime nginx uses locations in this directory for buffering different communications.  I'm guessing if nginx chose to write to the fastcgi buffer but failed was source of this problem.